# Issue while getting array value in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am using NodeJS to count the number of employees in different section. I am using Mongoose as ODM and MongoDB as database.That is my code (very simple for testing purposes).

```
   exports.list= function( req, res){
    var array = ['sectionA', 'sectionB'];
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
        Issue.count({ 'section.name': array[i]}, function (err, count) {
          console.log('Section name is: ' + array[i] + ' number of employees: ' + count );
        )};
     }
    }
```

But the value of `array[i`] is undefined inside `Issue.count({ 'section.name': array[i]}, function (err, count) {});`. But the value of count is absolutely right. I want an output like:

```
Section name is: sectionA number of employees: 50
Section name is: sectionB number of employees: 100
```

But my current output is

```
 Section name is: undefined number of employees: 50
 Section name is: undefined number of employees: 100
```

This is because value of `i` inside `Issue.count({ 'section.name': array[i]}, function (err, count) {});` is always 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@eshortie is correct: `Issue.count` is asynchronous and that's causing the problem.

Here's a solution:

```
for (i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
  Issue.count({ 'section.name': array[i]}, function(sectionName, err, count) {
    console.log('Section name is: ' + sectionName + ' number of employees: ' + count );
  }.bind(null, array[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible that Issue.count function is asynchronous? So your loop is completing before the callback of:

```
function (err, count) {
  console.log('Section name is: ' + array[i] + ' number of employees: ' + count );
}
```

is executed. When the callbacks are executed the value of i is undefined as a result.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to execute asynchronous functions using a regular `for` loop. It is asking for problems. Use `async.eachSeries` or `async.each` instead https://github.com/caolan/async#eachseriesarr-iterator-callback

```
var async = require('async')
var Issue = {} // mongoose isue model here
var elements = ['foo', 'bar']
async.eachSeries(
  elements,
  function(name, cb) {
    var query = {
      'section.name': name
    } 
    Issue.count(query, function(err, count) {
      if (err) { return cb(err) }
      console.dir(name, count)
    })
  },
  function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.dir(err)
    }
    console.log('done getting all counts')
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Using Q library

```
  var Q = require('q')
    var i = 0;

    function hello (item){

       var defer = Q.defer();

        Issue.count({'section.name': student}, function (err, count) {
               if(err){

                 defer.reject(err);

                }else{

                 var result = 'Section name is: ' + item + ' number of employees: ' + count ;
                 defer.resolve(result)

                 }

            });

    })
           return defer.promise;
      }


      function recall(){
        hello(checkItems[i]).then((val)=>{
          console.log(val)
          if(i < checkItems.length - 1){
            i++
            recall();
          }
        })
      }
    recall()
```